# Create a file to keep track of task progress

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, file

Running a script for datasets transfer that requires nearly 3-4months to complete via ssh. Unfortunately, connection break after 6-8days so a restart required.

Script:

```
import psycopg2
from time import sleep
from config import config
from tqdm import tqdm
import requests
import json
import subprocess

subprocess.call("./airquality.sh", shell=True)

def val_json():
    db = "select to_json(d) from (  select \
        a.particles_data as particles, \
        a.o3_data as \"O3\", \
        to_timestamp(a.seconds) as \"dateObserved\", \
        l.description as name, \
            json_build_object( \
                'coordinates', \
                json_build_array(l.node_lon, l.node_lat) \
            ) as location \
        from airquality as a \
            inner join deployment as d on \
                d.deployment_id = a.deployment_id \
            inner join location as l on \
                l.location_id = d.location_id \
    ) as d"
    return db

def main():

    url = 'http://localhost:1026/v2/entities/003/attrs?options=keyValues'
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json", \
               "fiware-service": "urbansense",  \
               "fiware-servicepath": "/basic"}
    conn = None
    try:
        params = config()
        with psycopg2.connect(**params) as conn:
            with conn.cursor(name='my_cursor') as cur:
                cur.itersize = 2000
                cur.execute(val_json())
       # row = cur.fetchone()
                for row in tqdm(cur):
                    jsonData = json.dumps(row)
                    if jsonData.startswith('[') and jsonData.endswith(']'):
                        jsonData = jsonData[1:-1]
                        print(jsonData)
                    requests.post(url, data= jsonData, headers=headers)
                    sleep(1)

                cur.close()
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        if conn is not None:
            conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How do I create a file and keep track of transfer progress, so when this script is run again (after a connection lost), datasets are fetched from where it stops previously?

**EDIT:**

Oops! I'm lost somewhere along the way.
I managed to have the scripts run and write progress to a text file (`air.txt`) which I manually created with content `0` (otherwise script won't run at all).
When this script run, content of `air.txt` file gets updated with cursor position value.

**Problem:**

I problem now is that when I stopped the script running (as a way of checking), and restarts again to make sure it picks from previous position, scripts start from `0` again overwriting previous value (and start a new count, instead of reading that as start position). 
Below is my updated script:

```
def val_json():
    db = "select to_json(d) from (  select \
        a.particles_data as particles, \
        a.o3_data as \"O3\", \
        to_timestamp(a.seconds) as \"dateObserved\", \
        l.description as name, \
            json_build_object( \
                'coordinates', \
                json_build_array(l.node_lon, l.node_lat) \
            ) as location \
        from airquality as a \
            inner join deployment as d on \
                d.deployment_id = a.deployment_id \
            inner join location as l on \
                l.location_id = d.location_id \
    ) as d"
    return db

def main():
    RESTART_POINT_FILE = 'air.txt'
    conn = None
    try:
        params = config()
        with open(RESTART_POINT_FILE) as fd:
           rows_to_skip = int(next(fd))
    #except OSError:
        rows_to_skip = 0
        with psycopg2.connect(**params) as conn:
            with conn.cursor(name='my_cursor') as cur:
                cur.itersize = 2000
                cur.execute(val_json())

                for processed_rows, row in enumerate(tqdm(cur)):
                    if processed_rows < rows_to_skip: continue
                    jsonData = json.dumps(row)
                    if jsonData.startswith('[') and jsonData.endswith(']'):
                        jsonData = jsonData[1:-1]

                        print('\n', processed_rows, '\t', jsonData)
                    #update progress file...
                    with open(RESTART_POINT_FILE, "w") as fd:
                        print(processed_rows, file=fd)
                    sleep(1)

                cur.close()
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)

    finally:
        if conn is not None:
            conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be to use a dedicated file on a well known place.

That file would contain a single line with the number of rows successfully processed, or be absent.

At start, if the file is absent the number of records to skip will be 0, and if present, the number of records do skip will be the number on first line of the file. The loop should be changed to skip those records and keep track of the number of the last processed record.

On a successful termination, the file should be deleted, and on error if should be written with the number of the last successfully processed record.

Skeletal code:

```
RESTART_POINT_FILE = ... # full path of the restart point file

# begin: read the file:
try:
    with open(RESTART_POINT_FILE) as fd:
        rows_to_skip = int(next(fd))
except OSError:
    rows_to_skip = 0

# loop:

                for processed_row, row in enumerate(tqdm(cur)):
                    if processed_row < rows_to_skip: continue
                    ...

# end
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)
        # write the file
        with open(RESTART_POINT_FILE, "w") as fd:
            print(processed_rows, file=fd)
    finally:
        if conn is not None:
            conn.close()
        # try to remove the file if it exists
        try:
            os.remove(RESTART_POINT_FILE)
        except OSError:
            pass
```

BEWARE: nothing has been tested...

Comment: this sounds a good solution to my problem pretty well. Can you please share some skeletal code showing how this could be achieved?

Comment: following with your solution, I only need fix some issues please (as in my question edit).

Answer (score 0):

try to to use while loop for the connection with True or fals and when connection is fals  do wait till its true again

Comment: would appreciate if you could kindly elaborate your answer please. No need to create the progress file?

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is solely due to timeout of your ssh remote terminal then the easy answer is: use a terminal multiplexer like **tmux**, **screen** that will run on the remote machine, and keep your program running even with sessions timeouts, you will only neeed to reconnect when convenient and reattach the terminal to see it processing or even a "terminal detacher" like **nohup** (but then you'll need to redirect stdout on a file if necessary).

However that won't save you from the occasionnal OOM kill, server reboot, ...), for this a regular serialization of the program state, with a reload mechanism is a good idea

Comment: I'm using `screen` sessions already, but for no clear reason the script stops  running after some days, though there is available  `screen` session to be resumed. On attaching the session again, I found that the python script stops running with last executed transactions and a `connection already closed` message.

Comment: Then it's probably your database server kicking you out, you could enhance your script to safely handle the connection closed on the database size, currently the exception handler will trigger and your script will exit.

Comment: can you please elaborate how "to safely handle connection closed" in your last comment? Is there a way for force the server maintain my connection?

Comment: Expecting the server to maintain the connection indefinitely is not "safe", you can however check the connection state, re-connect when needed and re-issue the request using LIMIT to skip over already processed lines.

Comment: Also you might want to inspect what's taking so long in your data transfert, an if it's the query then update it for better perfomances, and if it's not the database then use some local buffer to avoid having a query running for so long, that's not good database handling

Comment: that's the scenario I want, save number of processed rows to `air.txt` so when connection closed happens, skip processed rows (LIMIT) and continue. I edited my question with the script, but upon re-connect, it starts all over again.